# Persistent variable in view

Tags: sql, view, crystal-reports

I have this issue where I would like to use a variable that only changes under certain conditions...

```
1 Item1 <parent>
2 Item2 <child>
3 Item3 <child>
4 Item4 <child>
5 Item5 <parent>
6 Item6 <child>
```

I have a data table that once you select the parent item, it populates the associated child items below it.
The problem I have though, is I would like to identify the parent that the child item belongs to - and the only way in the data is the order in which they arrive (ie each child item is the child of the last parent item in the sequence)

If I could use a variable - then I could just assign the value to the variable each time a parent is identified - and print out the value of that variable on each line. Something like this:

```
1 Item1 <parent> Item1
2 Item2 <child>  Item1
3 Item3 <child>  Item1
4 Item4 <child>  Item1
5 Item5 <parent> Item5
6 Item6 <child>  Item5
```

So I know which parent each child belongs to. Is there anyway in a view that I can get an output like the one above (I need to use a view as I would like to link the output in a crystal report ultimately)

As a follow up to my comment below ... here's the way I would like the code to work for multiple orders on my system, hopefully it makes sense!

```
with 
parent_ranges as(
    select SOHNUM_0,ITMREF_0 as ITM, SOPLIN_0, LEAD(SOPLIN_0, 1, NULL) over (order by SOHNUM_0,SOPLIN_0) NX
   from <MY_DB>.SORDERP with (nolock)
 where LINTYP_0 = 6 –Parent
--and SOHNUM_0 = '<My Order Number>'
) 
select case when t1.LINTYP_0 in (6,7,8,9) then isnull(t2.ITM,'?') else 'NO'  end as PARENT_ITEM, t1.LINTYP_0,t1.ITMREF_0   
from <MY_DB>.SORDERP t1 with (nolock)
left join parent_ranges t2 on (t1.SOHNUM_0 = t2.SOHNUM_0 and t1.SOPLIN_0 >=  t2.SOPLIN_0 and ((t1.SOPLIN_0 < t2.NX) OR t2.NX IS NULL))
where t1.SOHNUM_0 = '<My Order Number>'
```

Can you see a way that I don't need to have the 
    --and SOHNUM_0 = ''
line in the view?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From sql-server 2012 you can use `LEAD` function:

```
;with 
parent_ranges as(
    select *, LEAD(id, 1, NULL) over (order by id) NX
    from @tbl
    where kind = 'parent'
) 
select T1.*, T2.Item PARENT_ITEM
from @tbl t1
left join parent_ranges t2 on t1.id >= t2.ID and (t1.id < t2.NX OR t2.NX IS NULL)
```

Comment: I have adapted it to work on my system - but it only works where I'm dealing with one dataset (in this case, an order table). If I restrict the parent_ranges where kind='parent' AND order_no = <my order> and have the same AND order_no = <my order> on the outer select, it works ... in order to have this in a view, I can't have the initial order restriction ... I hope that makes sense!

Comment: I think I may have worked this out myself .... If I use LEAD again to give me the next SOHNUM in the inner select, then in the outer select Ican use the criteria if NX is NULL or LEAD SOHNUM (ORDNO) <> SOHNUM ... that seems to work